# Elimination of hydroxyl group while deprotecting acetal

Tags: organic-chemistry

Regarding this reaction, other than de-protecting the acetal, will we have an elimination reaction for the alcohol or no?

[image]

Comment: Base is of no relevance here. It depends entirely on how strong the acid conditions are. It is easy to select conditions that will deprotect without elimination though you could easily form the hemi-acetal of the ketone.

Comment: You can't eliminate hydroxyl groups with base

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! We have a site policy for [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) questions. Please edit your question to include your attempt at the problem, where you got stuck, and let us know where you're finding difficulty so we may best help you.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments, it entirely depends on the conditions. It is easy to select mild conditions to cleave the dioxolane. Elimination would require very strong forcing conditions (concentrated acid and heating). The first site of protonation is the carbonyl, so you would form the hemi-acetal of the product long before elimination or substitution occured at the primary alcohol. If you were foolish enough to heat this with cH2SO4 then you could get elimination of the primary alcohol and generate quite a mess.